# Why ambiguous during pass list as parameter?

Tags: c++

How to resolve this compilation error? The compilation log said the caller and candidate are exactly the same, but there is overloaded and ambigous?
Code:

```
Ctrl.h
namespace CvRcgCtrllr {
    bool AssignPidsTo(const list<unsigned int> & pids, CvRcg & rcg);
    bool RemovePidsFrom(const list<unsigned int> & pids, CvRcg & rcg);
};

Ctrl.cpp
using namespace CvRcgCtrllr;
         30 bool AssignPidsTo(const list<unsigned int> & pids, Rcg & rcg)
         31 {     
         44     return true;
         45 }
         46
         47 bool RemovePidsFrom(const list<unsigned int> & pids, Rcg & rcg)
         48 {
         49     
         50     //Rcg default_rcg = GetNewRcg("default");
         51     //bool res = AssignPidsTo(pids, default_rcg);
         52     return res;
         53 }

<!-- -->

CvRcgCtrllr.cpp: In function ‘bool RemovePidsFrom(const std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >&, Rcg&)’:
CvRcgCtrllr.cpp:51: error: call of overloaded ‘AssignPidsTo(const std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >&, Rcg&)’ is ambiguous
CvRcgCtrllr.cpp:30: note: candidates are: bool AssignPidsTo(const std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >&, Rcg&)
CvRcgCtrllr.h:20: note:                 bool CvRcgCtrllr::AssignPidsTo(const std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >&, Rcg&)
```

Comment: I suspect you are not showing enough code to reason about your error.  The compiler message suggests that there is your `AssignPidsTo` function and then *another* `AssignPidsTo` function as a member inside the `CvRcgCtrllr` class.

Comment: CvRcgCtrllr is a namespace and AssignPidsTo is a function inside this namespace. After I change AssignPidsTo  to CvRcgCtrllr::AssignPidsTo, it said CvRcgCtrllr::AssignPidsTo is undefined.

Comment: You should definitely show more code. Try to make the shortest code sample that can replicate now.

Comment: It seems that you have declared a code inside namespace, and define in global namespace...

Comment: I'm going to further @Jarod42 s comment, which I think is likely the answer, in saying by the looks of it `RemovePidsFrom` was also supposed to  be defined within the `CvRcgCtrllr::`.

Comment: In addition to the global namespace problem, your method signatures don't agree. You have `CvRcg` in the declaration and `Rcg`in the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define namespace members by just doing

```
using namespace CvRcgCtrllr;
```

and then specifying members without scope resolution operator. It does not work as you think it works. In your code you declared a pair of functions inside `CvRcgCtrllr` and then additionally defined a pair of completely independent functions in *global* namespace. This is what causes ambiguity during overload resolution.

In order to define your functions from `CvRcgCtrllr` namespace in `.cpp` file you have to either reopen the namespace

```
namespace CvRcgCtrllr
{
  bool AssignPidsTo(const list<unsigned int> & pids, Rcg & rcg)
  {
    // Whatever
  }
}
```

or use qualified names of the functions

```
bool CvRcgCtrllr::AssignPidsTo(const list<unsigned int> & pids, Rcg & rcg)
{
  // Whatever
}
```

There's no way to avoid either this or that. `using namespace CvRcgCtrllr;` will not help you here.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
using namespace CvRcgCtrllr;
```

by

```
namespace CvRcgCtrllr
{
    // Your code of the file
}
```